# How to retain the state of dropdown after performing a POST request in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a page that contains three dropdowns **1. Select question type**, **2. Select Marks**, **3. Available Tags** which are part of **QuestionFilterForm**. And then I have another form called **QuestionPaperForm** on the same page inside the `<form>`. When I select a question type, a list of questions is visible on the same page after a post request. And then I can select one or many from the list of new questions which is another **POST** request (to add these questions to another list). After the second **POST** request when I try to refresh the page, chrome shows an alter of form resubmission. In this case, I thought of doing redirect after **POST**, but then with **redirect**, I can't retain the options selected in the dropdown. I have to each time select options and view the list of questions. I am not able to think of a good logic where I can handle the redirect issue.

My view is as follows

```
def design_questionpaper(request, course_id, quiz_id, questionpaper_id=None):
    context = {}
    user = request.user

    if quiz_id:
        quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)

    if questionpaper_id is None:
        question_paper = QuestionPaper.objects.get_or_create(
            quiz_id=quiz_id
        )[0]
    else:
        question_paper = get_object_or_404(
            QuestionPaper, id=questionpaper_id, quiz_id=quiz_id
        )
    questions, state = None, None
    marks = request.POST.get('marks', None)
    state = request.POST.get('is_active', None)
    question_type = request.POST.get('question_type', None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        filter_form = QuestionFilterForm(request.POST, user=user)

        if question_type:
            questions = _get_questions(user, question_type, marks)

        if questions:
            questions = _remove_already_present(questionpaper_id, questions)


        if 'add-fixed' in request.POST:
            return redirect(
                'yaksh:designquestionpaper',
                course_id=course_id,
                quiz_id=quiz_id,
                questionpaper_id=questionpaper_id
            )
        # question_paper.update_total_marks()
        # question_paper.save()

        # context['qpaper'] = question_paper
        # context['questions'] = questions
    else:
        filter_form = QuestionFilterForm(user=user)

    fixed_questions = question_paper.get_ordered_questions()
    
    context['qpaper'] = question_paper
    context['questions'] = questions
    context['fixed_questions'] = fixed_questions
    context['filter_form'] = filter_form
    context['course_id'] = course_id
    context['state'] = state
    return render(request, 'yaksh/design_questionpaper.html', context)
```

Comment: You can try saving those options in the frontend localstorage. Also can you show some frontend code.

Comment: Django used to include a form wizard for creating multi step forms, it may be useful for you. It’s moved to a separate package now https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html